# Access scope directive from a child element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to access the `directive scope` from a children element, triggering a function of test, but it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div my-directive>

     <div ng-click="triggerFromDirective('hello')">Click me</div>

</div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {

      return {
          scope: {},
          controller: function($scope) {

              // This function doesn't fire when click on the 
              // element
              $scope.triggerFromDirective = function(msg) {
                   alert(msg);
              }
          }
      }
});
```

Is it possible to trigger a function on the directive in this way? If no, how do you achieve that?

Comment: Typically, it's not a good design to mix scopes. The consumer of your directive (living in the outer scope) would not typically know of `triggerFromDirective` (defined in the isolate scope of the directive)

Comment: I think this [image](http://angular-tips.com/images/transclusionscopes/diag2.jpg) pretty much sums it up. The inner element has a sibling scope to "my-directive". The way to get `triggerFromDirective` to execute is to include it as a template in `my-directive`.

Comment: @NewDev Thanks that's true, Pete Yhea I got it thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, as New Dev said, the scopes are being mixed up. The code inside the directive div is not automatically added to the directive. I not 100% sure what your goal is here but usually a template is used to add HTML to the directive. This template will have access to the directive scope.

You can also take a look at [ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).

See here for an example http://jsfiddle.net/8Lbrsw35/.
And here is the code:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="app">
        <div my-directive></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        template: '<div ng-click="triggerFromDirective(\'hello\')">Click me</div>',
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.triggerFromDirective = function(msg) {
               alert(msg);
        };
    }
};
```

});